Can I load a flutter module from a remote github repository in iOS swift App?
I am trying to add a flutter module to existing iOS native app by following Add to App flutter guide. But I want to load module in the iOS pod file from a github repo instead of using a local path. Is that possible?
I certainly can publish a flutter package or plugin to pub.dev or github but I can't use package in native iOS project directly(with cocoapods) without having a flutter module first. Any help much appreciated.
Thanks.

So why don't you create an empty module which will have your current flutter module as a dependency in pubspec.yml. In pubspec yaml file your module may be added as a github link or dart pub link (here are options https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/using-packages) But to make this work and provide an access to your classes you will need to add main.dart file with exports in empty module.

@KonstantinVolkov- that is possible, but I wanted to expose flutter package/module as an sdk library to third party developer. With this intermediary module, distribution is not clean, like I'd need manually share the empty module with them instead of them downloading directly from a package repository. Also, changes in package could need changes in empty module(ex. signature changes for methods).
